# Cron format for day on multiple weeks

Tags: cron

i am using below link to test cron format
https://cronexpressiondescriptor.azurewebsites.net/

i want to have cron format for second and fourth wednesday
e.g. 0 19 * * 3#2,3#4
but the above example didn't work.comma doesn't work here?
any idea?

Comment: Try adding multiple lines as one for second Wednesday and one for Fourth wednesday

Comment: multiple means separate it? i tried like '0 19 * * 3#2 0 19 * * 3#4' but throws error as 'Expression has too many parts (10). Expression must not have more than 7 parts.'

Comment: No separate lines altogether. In first line `0 19 * * 3#2` and in second line `0 19 * *3#4`

Comment: means there is no way to have it in one line for putting multiple weeks?